# How to add "system" local user like mysql or tomcat?

Tags: users, useradd

My system has a lot of users, I'v never created, like `mysql` or `tomcat`. These users have no home directories inside `/home`

Obviously, a daemon programs run under these users.

What is the term for such users?

How to create my own user of such kind? For example, I wish to create a user for `deluged`, but I don't want to create and remember a password for it and also don't want to allow somebody to login with this user from console.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can give useradd the `-r` or `--system` flags to tell it you want such a user (a system user as you already called it).  Here's an excerpt from my system's man page:

> ```
> -r, --system
>        Create a system account.
>
>        System users will be created with no aging information in
>        /etc/shadow, and their numeric identifiers are choosen in the
>        SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in /etc/login.defs, instead
>        of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their GID counterparts for the creation of
>        groups).
>
>        Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an
>        user, regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs
>        (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the -m options if you want a
>        home directory for a system account to be created.
> ```

Though you can make any user unable to login from the console by setting their shell to `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` or something like that.  You can do that with `-s` to `useradd` or you can change an existing user with `chsh -s /sbin/nologin` for example.

Comment: Will I still be able to login such user with FTP for example or other client?

Comment: @Dims if you don't set a password for the user then you likely won't be able to login as it.  These types of users are mostly commonly used by having root `su` to that user to adopt more restricted privileges, not for any sort of "normal" activity

Comment: I did this for `deluge` right now and found I am unable to do `su` for this user, because it asks a password, which was not created...

Comment: @dims are you root when you try to `su` to `deluge`?  Non-root users have to provide the target user's password to become them

Comment: I am usually trying to be non-root and issue `sudo` when required to elevate... So I need to be "more" root, right?

Comment: @dims well you could do `sudo su - deluge` to  execute the `su` with root privileges

Answer (score 1):

You add the users the same way as the normal ones. Just make their shell path `/sbin/nologin` and you're okay.

Read up on the useradd manual for more info: `$ man useradd`